# PWA - How to send push notifications to all subscribed users

Tags: javascript, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I would like to set up a notifications system to be used when a new update of my progressive web app is available.
The pwa uses react and has node (with express) as the backend.

I followed google's guide to push notifications ([link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/)) and everything works fine when sending a push message from the devTools' service workers tab.

The problem is that the guide ends there and i would like to be able to send a notification to every subscribed user.
I tried to look for a solution and i found out that Firebase Cloud Messaging could do what i need, but when i tried to implement it i got a bit confused as it seems quite different from what I've done in the guide mentioned above.
I've also looked at other guides here and there but they don't do what i need and some of them doesn't even work.

Can someone please explain me what should i do the get that result?
Thanks in advance for the help, i hope my question isn't too stupid '^^

Comment: There is much to learn and many variations. Nobody would be able to teach you all the "how-to" in an answer to a question here. The Google Developers video channel has many good videos on the topic (https://youtu.be/ggUY0Q4f5ok) once you have tried getting something going and get stuck, ask your specific question (with code examples) here and somebody could probably help.